# How do I arrange SwiftUI Toolbar items?

Tags: ios, user-interface, swiftui, ios-simulator, toolbar

I have a SwiftUI ToolBar with 4 buttons, however the code I implemented is not correct because the buttons end up in weird places when changing the device type in simulator.

Even worse, when viewed on iPhone 8 / 8 Plus, 2 of the buttons are on the far edges of the window.

How do I properly apply spacing/padding to ToolBar buttons so they are consistent across different iOS devices?

Thank you!

[image: IPhone 8]

```
 // This code spaces the buttons but they change positions depending on the iOS device


                 ToolbarItem {
                        HStack {
                            HStack {
                                ProfileUploadMediaButton()
                            }.padding([.trailing], 85)
                            HStack {
                                ProfileUsernameButton()
                            }.padding([.trailing], 84)
                            HStack {
                                ProfileLiveButton()
                            }.padding([.trailing], 6)
                            HStack {
                                AccountButton()
                            }.padding([.trailing], 12)
                        }
                    }
                })
```

[image: IPhone Pro Max]

```
// I was thinking code like this but all buttons are bunched together on the right-side of  // the screen...

                    ToolbarItem {
                        HStack {
                            ProfileUploadMediaButton()
                            ProfileUsernameButton()
                            ProfileLiveButton()
                            AccountButton()
                        }
                    }
```

[image: Items are all bunched together]

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think you can add some sort of spacing element in between each one. (I think it's called flexible space) Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you add ToolbarItems, there is an initializer where you can explicitly set the placement of each item. For your case, you would add 3 ToolbarItems, for the left, center, and right. I'd mention that the toolbar is meant to be dynamic, so it may look different on different devices on purpose.

```swift
struct ToolbarView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test")
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Username")
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "dot.radiowaves.left.and.right")
                        Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

}
```

Per the documentation, here are the placement options. I'm guessing that when you don't explicitly add a placement, they default to .automatic.

- automatic:
  The item is placed automatically, depending on many factors including the platform, size class, or presence of other items.
- bottomBar:
  The item is placed in the bottom toolbar. Applies to iOS, iPadOS, and Mac Catalyst.
- cancellationAction:
  The item represents a cancellation action for a modal interface.
- confirmationAction:
  The item represents a confirmation action for a modal interface.
- destructiveAction:
  The item represents a destructive action for a modal interface.
- navigation:
  The item represents a navigation action.
- navigationBarLeading:
  The item is placed in the leading edge of the navigation bar. Applies to iOS, iPadOS, tvOS, and Mac Catalyst.
- navigationBarTrailing:
  The item is placed in the trailing edge of the navigation bar. Applies to iOS, iPadOS, tvOS, and Mac Catalyst.
- primaryAction:
  The item represents a primary action.
- principal:
  The item is placed in the principal item section.
- ToolbarItemPlacement:
  The item represents a change in status for the current context.

Comment: This approach doesn't work anymore. On Xcode 15.2 it causes error: `Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'ToolbarItem<(), some View>' conform to 'View'`